# Linked list: Should the type of pointer "next" and the name of struct be same?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, typedef

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct {
    int val;
    struct node* next;
} Node, *NodePtr;
void makeInitialLinkedList(int a[], int n)
{
    int i;
    NodePtr rec=NULL;
    NodePtr head=NULL;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        NodePtr cur=(NodePtr)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (i==0) head=cur;
        if (rec!=NULL) rec->next=(node*)cur;
        cur->val=a[i];
        cur->next=NULL;
        rec=cur;
    }

    // test
    while(n--) {
        printf("%d ", head->val);
        head=(NodePtr)head->next;
    }
}
NodePtr copy(NodePtr head)
{
    return NULL;
}
int main()
{
    //Mission #2
    int initialDataArray[10]={5,3,2,8,9,7,0,6,4,1};
    makeInitialLinkedList(initialDataArray, 10);

}
```

I do not understand why this works. I did not make a name initially for the struct and only made a surname "Node" by typedef. Then how does "struct node* next" work correctly? is node* a kind of data types like int* or char*? I thought like this:

```
typedef struct strName {
    int val;
    struct strName* next;
} strSurName, *strPtr;
```

Does the type of pointer "next" and the initial name of struct have to same?

Comment: In general I believe it is good to have the same type, but it is up to you. It can be also of type `void *`

Comment: Don't hide pointer semantics behind a typedef just to have syntactic sugar.

Comment: Not a good practice to `typedef` pointers; this is likely to lead to errors and confusion.

Comment: I know this is not good, but my stupid professor sticks to this way.. lol

Comment: typedef struct strName {
    int val;
    struct anyNameIPut* next;
} strSurName, *strPtr;

Comment: can i put any name for the next pointer's type?

Comment: "I do not understand why this works." - well the code you've posted does *not* compile -- because `node` is not defined just as you thought

Comment: Your prof insits on this horrible practice? I guess it's true that those who can't do, teach.

Comment: (1) it runs at dev c++ well (2) then how can i fix this? i am weak at pointer pls help..

Comment: I'm sorry you find pointers difficult, but this horrible habit your professor dictates is only going to make it harder for you to understand.

Comment: When you say "this works" do you really mean "I don't get a compile error at the point the struct is defined, even though there may be other errors later"?

Comment: @Ingo Leonhard: it does compile, but it does not behave as intended.

Comment: @StephanLechner it doesn't, see gsamaras' answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `struct node* next` as a member of your (unnamed) struct, you actually do two things - forward declare a structure `struct node` and define a member named `next` as a pointer to the (forward declared) `struct node`. Note that `struct node`, as it has been just forward declared, is incomplete and is an *additinal, new* structure that is different from the enclosing struct you actually wanted to refer to. Confer also [struct forward declaration at cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct):

> A declaration of the following form `struct name;` hides any
>   previously declared meaning for the name name in the tag name space
>   and declares name as a new struct name in current scope, which will be
>   defined later. Until the definition appears, this struct name has
>   incomplete type. This allows structs that refer to each other:

```
struct y;
struct x { struct y *p; /* ... */ };
struct y { struct x *q; /* ... */ };
```

So It just *seems* as if you had a pointer to the same `struct` you are defining, but actually you are (forward declaring) and using a new structure. See the following example, which actually compiles.

```
struct known_struct {
    int a[20];
};

struct own_struct {
    int val;
    struct known_struct* known;
    struct own_struct *own;
    struct unknown_struct* unknown;
} test;

int main(){

    size_t sizeOfKnownMember = sizeof(*(test.known));  // gives 80
    size_t sizeOfMemberOwn = sizeof(*(test.own));  // gives 32
    // size_t sizeOfunknownMember = sizeof(*(test.unknown));  // invalid application of sizeof to incomplete type `struct unknown_struct`

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right. It works because next is a pointer and you it is never actually dereferenced. Only the address is passed around and manipulated (which do not really requires `node` to be complete). If you actually try to print `next->val` then you will see the problem appearing cause at that point the compiler need to know the size of `node` which has only been forward declared. Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not understand why this works.

It doesn't, you should get compilation errors, like these with gcc 6.3 or 4.2.1:

```
prog.c: In function ‘makeInitialLinkedList’:
prog.c:15:35: error: ‘node’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         if (rec!=NULL) rec->next=(node*)cur;
                                   ^~~~
prog.c:15:35: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
prog.c:15:40: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
         if (rec!=NULL) rec->next=(node*)cur;
                                        ^
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3512293b47e95856)</kbd> by Deduplicator.

> is node* a kind of data types like int* or char*?

No. What you have there will result in an error, unless you define `node` yourself.

> Does the type of pointer "next" and the initial name of struct have to same?

That's the idea.

Comment: this runs at dev c++ compiler

Comment: @keist99 See the errors on Coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3512293b47e95856

Comment: @keist99 that's an old compiler. Try the code online, in Ideone for example and will get errors! Deduplicator nice, I will inject this link in my answer, if you don't mind. =)